# How Do I Work on Xcode Projects on Multiple Computers?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am attempting to store my Xcode project files on iCloud Drive, with hopes of accessing them on multiple computers. I am having an issue with a project when accessed from a second computer. The project builds and runs fine in the simulator, but the storyboard is missing objects and just looks completely different.

I am learning git at the moment, so I will eventually handle this properly. But as I learn Swift and programming in general, I thought this method would be easiest for now.

Any ideas what could be causing the storyboard to be different on the second computer?

Thank you.

Comment: Forget that; learn git now and start using it.  Create an account on bitbucket.org which is free for small (< 5 man) teams.

Answer (score 4):

Just spend a day or two to learn git, you will thank yourself later. Saving the files on a cloud drive will lead to many headaches.

Answer (score 2):

Forget that; learn git now and start using it.

Create an account on [bitbucket.org](https://bitbucket.org/) to store your repos privately, which is free for small (< 5 man) teams.